# numpy.dot() and numpy.meshgrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

There is a way to evaluate a function that include dot product avoiding to use itertool.product but numpy.meshgrid?

Itertool method to compute cartesian product:

```
w=np.array([[1,1],[2,2]])
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 2)   
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 2)

cartesian_grid=np.array([ i for i in itertools.product(x,y)])

z=np.dot(w,cartesian_grid.T)
```

I want to do something like this:

```
np_mesh=np.meshgrid(x,y)

z=np.dot(w,np.mesh?)
```

Principally to use plot surface of matplotlib

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you explain it?

Comment: how to pass a numpy.meshgrid as arguments of numpy.dot to get the same result of the first chunk